# Feature matching - Minimum numbers of matches

Tags: opencv, matching, sift, surf, orb

I'm playing with "feature matching" in OpenCV. For different types of matching methods, we need to define a condition (i.e. OpenCV – SIFT SURF ORB tutorial MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10) regarding the minimum number of matches.

I'm wondering if there is any kind of standard or golden standard method or criteria for setting this condition? 
How can / should we technically get this sort of threshold or condition?

Even a rule of thumb suggested would be help.

Thank you so much,

Comment: depends on your application ;) you could analyze with ROC-curve or similar

Comment: Thanks.  What else do you suggest instead of ROC?

Comment: Any other thoughts are much appreciated .

Comment: Any update from experts in this field is much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

One way is ROC and you can check FREAK and BRISK .